# iOS7.1 MKMapView selectAnnotation issue

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotationview, ios7.1

so since iOS7.1 came out, I keep having problems with my code to select new annotations on the map when the users taps on the map. The code works find with iOS6 and 7, but is messing up on 7.1.

I didn't find any specific information on this problem, but here's my very simple code to illustrate the problem.

My header only contains this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MAViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mMapView;

@end
```

And my implementation file is like follows:

```
#import "MAViewController.h"

@interface MAViewController ()

@end

@implementation MAViewController

@synthesize mMapView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.mMapView setDelegate:self];
    [self.mMapView addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(mapTapped:)]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)mapTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{

    CGPoint touchPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self.mMapView];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate = [self.mMapView convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:self.mMapView];
    CLLocation *lTapLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:touchMapCoordinate.latitude longitude:touchMapCoordinate.longitude];

    [self.mMapView removeAnnotations:mMapView.annotations];

    MKPointAnnotation *lAnnotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    lAnnotation.coordinate = lTapLocation.coordinate;
    lAnnotation.title = @"TAP";

    [self.mMapView addAnnotation:lAnnotation];
}

#pragma mark - MapView Delegate

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    if([annotation isKindOfClass: [MKUserLocation class]]) {
        return nil;
    }

    MKPinAnnotationView *lPin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil];
    lPin.canShowCallout = FALSE;

    return lPin;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    MKAnnotationView *lAnnotationView = (MKAnnotationView*)[views objectAtIndex:0];
    lAnnotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

    if ([lAnnotationView.annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        return;
    }

    [mapView selectAnnotation:lAnnotationView.annotation animated:YES];
}

@end
```

I just added a MKMapView in the storyboard, nothing more.
Thanks for sharing your ideas on the problem.

The problem is, the annotation is selected and deselected at once, and the user needs to tap on it again to display the title.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was asked two months ago but I'm currently facing the same problem.

Currently I'm using a workaround where I select the annotation with a small delay after adding it to the mapView. This seems to work with delays >= 0.4s. But with delays < 0.4s it gets deselected immediately after selecting. Very strange:

```
//In the onClick handler
MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
annotation.coordinate = tapCoord;
self.lastAnnotation = annotation;
[self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
[self performSelector:@selector(selectLastAnnotation) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.4];
```

and the helper method:

```
-(void)selectLastAnnotation{
    [self.mapView selectAnnotation:self.lastAnnotation animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing this right now. I won't accept your answer as this is more of a quick fix than a solution, but it's still helpful.